# Download Dialog Not Popping Up in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, blob, microsoft-edge

I am getting a blob and I am embedding that into a hidden  tag. I use a button to trigger the function which sets the `href` to `url` created and then do a click. The file is being downloaded but in the background whereas in Chrome as soon as the file is downloaded I get that download popup with the filename. Opening the URL using `window.open(url,'_blank')` solves this but I am not able to get the desired filename in that method.

```js
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setFileDownloadUrl(url);
    downloadLinkRef.current.download = filename;
    downloadLinkRef.current.target = "_blank";
    downloadLinkRef.current.click();
```

I have tried using all the target values but that didn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `setFileDownloadUrl` function - is that some non-standard Edge browser thing?

Comment: So is your problem that the file downloads in Edge but doesnt pop up a folder picker to say _where_ to download to (like in Chrome)? Because that sounds like a browser preference/choice that you won't be able to do much about.

Comment: @JaromandaX  setFileDownloadUrl just updates the Url state in React
const [fileDownloadUrl,setFileDownloadUrl] = React.useState(null);

Also this the anchor tag I am using.
      <a className="hidden"
             href={fileDownloadUrl}
             ref={downloadLinkRef}
          >Download SPI</a>

Comment: @somethinghere No, its not about the location. Whenever I download in Chrome the file gets downloaded and chrome gives me a popup in right top corner with a small download like widget, same happens in Edge when I was using the href as a static file link, but after updating it dynamically (which is needed by me) it downloads the file but the download popup doesn't come up. 
This is the sample popup that I need - https://imgur.com/a/XaFnJWK

Comment: So the file gets downloaded, with the correct filename, but it just doesnt open the downloads popover? Because that's a browser-thing, not something you can do a lot about. Browsers might have different behaviours depending on what their users expect?

Comment: Which version of Edge do you use? If you download a file from other site, will the popup show in Edge? Could you please provide a screenshot of this page **edge://settings/downloads#All** in Edge? I also agree it's related with browser setting and browser behavior, which can't be controlled by code.